# How to Check File pattern exists on HTTP?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I need to check if a file or no. of files having a pattern in their file names are available on HTTP. and IF present then next will be to download them.

I know to check a particular file directly on HTTP but I am not sure how to achieve this with File name pattern like abc*.csv?

Comment: 1. If you can run code on the web server, you can get the server to check for you. 2. If you have FTP access to the directory, you could get a directory listing from that. 3. You can try every possible filename with your current method.

Comment: You can only check if a filename is following a pattern, not the other way around. So to do what you want, you'll need the list of files first or loop all possibility.

Comment: How can I get list of all files on HTTP site? I am not sure if there is any method to do so?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must check if the page exist:

```
using System.Net;
...
private bool CheckIfRemoteFileExist(string url){
    try
    {
        //Creating the HttpWebRequest
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        //Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        //Getting the Web Response.
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        //Returns TURE if the Status code == 200
        return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch
    {
        //Any exception will returns false.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, if it exist, you can download the page:

```
string content=string.Empty;
if(CheckIfRemoteFileExist("myUrl"))
    using(var client = new WebClient())
        content = client.DownloadString("myUrl");
else
    MessageBox.Show("File seems dosen't exist");
```

Comment: The issue with me is that I dont have full file name. I have to check if the file with filenames having "abc" exists. For eg. http: //www.url.com/abc*.txt